# UIImageView not showing

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I changed a .png that I was using for an UIIMageView that I added using InterfaceBuilder.  Now, when I run the app in the simulator, the image does not show.  I have tried removing the reference and re-adding and even creating a new image altogether and nothing seems to work.

PLEASE HELP!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a nice gotcha I just encountered causing exactly the problem you described. **If you have more than one 'target' set up** in your project then you need to pay attention to the 'target membership' information for an image resource. Select the image in xcode navigator panel, and you'll see this section in the right hand panel.  For some reason when you add a new image it will not, by default, be a member of all targets. So if you're running a target in the simulator for which this image is not a member...  then it won't show.

There's probably several gotchas that can cause a UIImageView to not work as expected.

More generally cleaning the project is probably a good suggestion.

For general info as well: xcode projects *appear* to have files and directories *contained* within them, but actually it stores path references which may or may not reflect what's going on in your file system. Selecting an image file in xcode reveals the real filesystem path it's stored at in the right hand side panel, or you can right-click 'show in finder'. It seems like you can accidentally create a spaghetti mess of references to other parts of the file system, so I guess we need to take care when adding files to a project. I suppose any broken path references would also stop the image being shown in Interface Builder, unless xcode is playing tricks on you with caching. You never can tell :-)

Answer (score 1):

If your .png has the same name as previous, IB doesn't recompile it's files. Try to clean your project, than build it.'

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure your connections are intact in Interface builder?

Comment: I actually rebuilt the NIB from scractch and re-attached all of the connections.  I even copied the /png file to a new name and added it to the new UIIMageView.  No luck.

Comment: ok..i've had one weird moment with UIImageView once. Could you please check in Interface Builder, UIImageView's image section, can you see/select the image which you wanted?? For a while i couldn't.. But then it worked after i removed the image and re-added..

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem now. Try to build and run your project from XCode. I did that and it showed all the background (and other) UIImageViews just fine. When I simulate the interface from Interface Builder, the backgrounds still do not show up, but it's a usable workaround for now.